# Javascript props assignment without key?

Tags: javascript

```
let text = 'how are you';
let foo = {
  type : 'foo',
  text
};
console.log(foo);
```

Why the key `text` is auto assigned, is there any reference on such syntax?

Comment: [Shorthand property names](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#Property_definitions)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a [shorter notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#Property_definitions) in ECMAScript 2015(ES6)  Object initializer.

```
//ES5
var a = "foo", 
    b = 42, 
    c = {};

var o = { 
  a: a,
  b: b,
  c: c
};

//ES6 shorter notation available to achieve the same:  
var o = { a, b, c };
```